# How to 'convert' hourly calculations from derived different time zones to PST for a daily calculation?

Tags: sql, oracle

So right now, a stored procedure that I wrote that calculates values for different time zones by hour. I already have a column called UTC_OFFSET that shows what time zone each entity is in. With these hourly values I have to calculate the total for each day but it has to be 'converted to Pacific Standard Time' (UTC_OFFSET = 5) prior to the aggregation/calculation. I am having a tough time wrapping my head around how to group the various scenarios (i.e. states that don't have DST, states in different time zones, etc.). The different time zones are signified by the UTC_OFFSET column.  I tried using a case statement but i am not sure how exactly i'd be able to tie that into my aggregations.

**NOTE:** the HR_NUM column is the Nth hour of the day in that time zone. The Value column is what we are trying to aggregate / sum to get the total value for that particular day.

**For example:** the 23rd Hour in PST (11:00 PM) will be the 2nd hour in EST (2:00 AM) of the next day (4/5/2018). However, if there is a value correlated to the EST UTC_OFFSET (5) for that time, the value will still need to be used to calculate the total for today (4/4/2018).

Below is some sample data that I have:

```
Calculation_ID    Entity     Value       HR                     UTC_OFFSET    HR_NUM     Data_Date
1                 1          8       18-APR-19 04.00.00 AM      5             1         1092019
2                 1          4       18-APR-19 05.00.00 AM      5             2         1092019
3                 1          5       18-APR-19 06.00.00 AM      5             3         1092019
4                 2          7       18-APR-19 01.00.00 AM      8             1         1092019
5                 2          12      18-APR-19 02.00.00 AM      8             2         1092019
6                 3          15      18-APR-20 01.00.00 AM      7             22        1102019
7                 4          22      18-APR-19 02.00.00 AM      5             2         1092019
8                 3          17      18-APR-19 12.00.00 AM      8             24        1092019
```

Below Is what I am trying to get:

```
 Entity_Id      Created_Dt        Value       UTC_Offset       Data_Date
 1              04-APR-17         17          5                1092019
 2              04-APR-17         19          8                1092019
 3              04-APR-17         15          7                1092019
 4              04-APR-17         22          5                1092019
```

The Data Date format is in the following format: (DDDYYYY).

Comment: ive built a utc offset lookup table. So i will just add a CASE statement to look whether its DST or not correct? Thanks! Not exactly sure what a POSIX date time object is, however. How would I be able to get the calculations based off a day in 'PST' for the other time zones? I couldn't really wrap my head around how that logic would need to be written...

Comment: How does your output relate to your input? `Created_dt` seems to come from nowhere. `Value` appears to be a sum, `UTC_offset` is the minimum and `data_date` is another random number ... why?

Comment: Also, why do you not just store the date/UTC offset as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type?

Comment: @MT0 created_dt is just a field in Oracle where Oracle logs what date the entry was made into the table / database . Most of the time create_dt is 'sysdate'.  Data_Date is the date that the Value is correlated to. In this case it would be the 'Number of Cones sold' on 1112019 (for example)

Comment: @Mako212 what exactly is a POSIX object? i'll probably have to do a google search on what that is.

Comment: Please modify your example to be a [MCVE] and remove everything that is not relevant to your question and is just going to confuse everyone who does not know your data as you do.

Comment: @MT0 How much more minimal would you like the data? I have a couple examples of each possible scenario so that every scenario is covered. I've taken out some of the columns

Comment: If they are relevant then you need to explain **why** because at the moment there is no logic why you need a `calculation_id`, `calculation_dt` or `hr_num` column in your input and how they are relevant to your output (if they are?) let alone the question about dates. Why is  the `value` column relevant to a question about dates (is it just a distraction)? If `created_dt`is just `SYSDATE` then it is not relevant... etc, etc...

Comment: @MT0 gotcha, thanks for breaking that down for me. I've edited my original question to take out those columns. the HR_NUM column is the Nth hour of the day. ( i will add that to my original question) . The value column is what we are trying to aggregate / sum to get the total value for that particular day. We are converting all of our timestamps to reflect a day in PST so our calculations will ultimately need to reflect that. For example: the 23rd Hour in PST (11:00 PM) will be the 2nd hour in EST (2:00 AM) of the next day. However, the value for that time will still need to be used for today.

Comment: How is Data_Date in the expected output calculated? It doesn't seem to bear any relationship to Data_Date in the input.

Comment: @Nick i made a typo, i corrected it (Sorry about that). The Data_Date should reflect the date that we are aggregating / summing all of the Hourly values for .

Comment: And how is HR_NUM related to HR? There doesn't seem to be a consistent relationship based on HR and UTC_OFFSET

Comment: It seems Data_Date for entity 4 should also be 1092019 as that is the only value for which there is data?

Comment: @Nick yes i corrected that, sorry. the HR_NUM is the hour # of that day. So for example: if HR was 3:00:00 AM, the HR_NUM would be 3. The HR_NUM shows what hour of that day is locally without converting back to PST. UTC_OFFSET is the absolute value of the number of hours its away from standard UTC time

Comment: For calculation_id 6 HR is 1am and HR_NUM is 22?

Comment: Yeah its the 22nd Hour of the previous day in PST

Comment: You said in your previous comment that HR_NUM is local time, not converted to PST...

Comment: crap, i wasnt thinking straight. you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store the values as a `DATE` data type with a separate `UTC_offset` column.

Store it as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and then you can use `AT TIME ZONE 'PST'` to convert to a common time zone.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Calculation_ID NUMBER(10,0),
  Entity         NUMBER(10,0),
  Value          NUMBER(10,0),
  HR             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO table_name
  SELECT 1, 1,  8, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 04:00:00+05:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1,  4, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 05:00:00+05:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1,  5, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 06:00:00+05:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2,  7, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 01:00:00+08:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 2, 12, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 02:00:00+08:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 3, 15, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-20 01:00:00+07:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 4, 22, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 02:00:00+05:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 5, 17, TIMESTAMP '2018-04-19 12:00:00+08:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Entity,
       SYSDATE AS Created_dt,
       SUM( VALUE ) AS value,
       TRUNC( HR AT TIME ZONE 'PST' ) AS day
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       entity,
       TRUNC( HR AT TIME ZONE 'PST' );
```

**Output**:

```
ENTITY  CREATED_DT  VALUE   DAY
------- ----------- ------- ---------
2       04-APR-18   19      18-APR-18
4       04-APR-18   22      18-APR-18
3       04-APR-18   15      19-APR-18
1       04-APR-18   17      18-APR-18
5       04-APR-18   17      18-APR-18
```

Comment: you are awesome, thank you so much. The current database is laid out like that so i may have to make a structural change.

Comment: what happens if we have to keep it as a timestamp column (no time zone) with a utc_offset? apparently what you suggested is a strucutral change that can't be implemented... :(

Comment: @JohnWick `TRUNC( FROM_TZ( HR, TO_CHAR( UTC_Offset, '00' ) || ':00' ) AT TIME ZONE 'PST' ) AS day` [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a27ab/6)

Comment: @JohnWick Just updated that comment as I think the first version was incorrect.